# Where oh where has my UAC password textbox gone?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade, uac

Finally decided to upgrade to Windows 10 (from Windows 7 Home Premium, Service Pack 1) and started the upgrade process. However, during the upgrade, it notified me that it was unable to finish and restarted the system.

Ever since, I have been unable to update the system in any way because the UAC dialog doesn’t contain a textbox to enter the administrator password. The system can be used but no updates can be performed including those for applications already installed.

Several searches show that I’m not the only one facing this issue, but the solutions offered like those in [this thread](http://blog.unixwiz.net/2009/05/windows-7-uac-where-do-i-type-the-administrator-password.html) haven’t worked for me.

When I attempt to boot into safe mode with command prompt, a low resolution login screen appears briefly (~2 seconds) that shows the icons for the accounts on my system. No adminstrator account is shown. But before I can do anything, the screen resets and Windows shows the normal login screen.